# Stop iOS 7 update installation

Tags: ios

I made a mistake and accidentally started downloading iOS 7 on my device.

I didn't notice it until it finished downloading but now it says it needs minimum of 50% charge to start installation.

I **do not want to install** and and I am concerned of charging my phone as the download might start automatically

Will it install automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It should not install until and unless you click on install.

Comment: This is true. The update will always require input from the user. When the download finishes, simply hit cancel when the prompt appears.